# Magento 1.9.x - 404 Errors on Prod Server But Not On Local Dev Machine

Tags: redirect, magento, http-status-code-404, magento-1.9

We've updated a Magento installation from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.6. Had to re-code a custom module. Everything is working just fine on our local dev machines, which are a clone of the production server:

Nginx, PHP 5.6.30, MySQL

When we push the revision to production, everything works just fine, the admin panel shows Magento 1.9.3.6 but this one custom module (which modifies the admin customer detail view) throws a 404 error once a form is submitted.

All of this works perfectly fine on our local dev.

We've deleted the cache, re-indexed all data and triple checked that the code was transferred correctly. Everything matches the local dev but the custom module throws a 404 error on the prod server.

My questions:

1. Any idea what is going on here ?
2. Since the 404 Magento error page does not state any useful debug information, how can we debug the routing on the prod server?

---

```
controller class located at \app\code\local\Test\CustomCustomerFields\controllers\Adminhtml\CustomCustomerFields\IndexController.php:

class Test_CustomCustomerFields_Adminhtml_CustomCustomerFields_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {}
```

module config.xml:

```
...
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
          <args>
              <modules>
                  <customcustomerfields before="Mage_Adminhtml">Test_CustomCustomerFields_Adminhtml</customcustomerfields>
              </modules>
          </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
...
```

Comment: check namespace and lower and upper case problem and if possible show me the xml and controller class

Comment: any suggestion from the browser inspector about the request relative to the module? Maybe you've forgot to change some base url while transferring the module from dev to prod. Have a look to the core_config_data table. 
check also the namespace in the controllers as already suggested.

Comment: @ sissy: the base url in the core_config_data table is correct, otherwise the entire prod site would not work.
@ faizanberg: could you elaborate on the lower/upper case problem ? Are you referring to the Controller class name ? that one is correct, otherwise it would not work on the dev stage.

Thanks !!!

Comment: I've added the controller class name as well as excerpt from config.xml file. Thanks.

Comment: check the url of the form or share the code with me its easy to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turned out to be a camelcase folder name problem that did NOT affect Ubuntu (local dev, Vagrant) as the custom module worked just fine over there, but on CentOS (prod server), the camelcase error triggered a not readable filepath, which in turn lead to the 404...

I debugged the routing via the \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php class.

Answer (score 0):

class Test_CustomCustomerFields_Adminhtml_CustomCustomerFields_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_CustomcustomerfieldsController